# In kubernetes How can I use metadata name from Replication Controller inside my pod?

Tags: kubernetes

In kubernetes How can I use metadata name from Replication Controller inside my pod?
Lets say I want to pass :

**name:** sparkworker1-rc

To my pods so I can use it as a parameter for log file, for example:

```
- name: "JAVA_OPTS"
  value: "-DMY_RC_NAME=$(MY_RC_NAME)"
```

But instead of getting **"sparkworker1-rc"** I get the name of the pod that is running sparkworker1-rc-(name_of_the_pod).

***This is my YAML:***

```
kind: ReplicationController
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: sparkworker1-rc
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    component: spark-worker1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: spark-worker1
      annotations:
        pod.beta.kubernetes.io/hostname: worker1
```

Does anyone knows how I can get the RC name and **NOT** the pod name?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure we can access the metadata value inside the container. other option is you can pass metadata as environment variable.

like this.

```
env:
        - name: METADATANAME
          value: sparkworker1-rc
```

Comment: It will work But I wanted to avoid writing the same value (sparkworker1-rc) twice.

Comment: refer this document see it helps: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/